# Ruby ActiveRecord has_one with conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have some `Item`s for sale, and I'm keeping track of their `Cost` historically:

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  # eg: costs.amount = 123.45; costs.item_id = 1; costs.created_at = 2011-08-11 16:28
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs

  # eg: items.id = 1; items.name = Cheese Sandwich
end
```

This code works, I can pull out all the previous costs for the item I'm selling.

I feel like it should be possible to have a second clause for `Item` so that I can pull out the current price directly:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs
  has_one :current_cost, :class_name => :costs, :conditions => 'MAX(created_at)'
end

my_item.current_cost # => <£123.45, 45 minutes ago>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs
  def current_cost
    self.costs.order("created_at DESC").first
  end
end

my_item.current_cost
```

Answer (score 2):

```
has_one :current_cost, :class_name => :costs, :order => 'create_at DESC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scope:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs
  scope :current_cost, limit(1).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

usage:

```
my_item.current_cost
```

Comment: this will not work like `has_one`..`my_item.current_cost` will still give an active record relation (which is like an array) and will have to call `my_item.current_cost.first` to get the record.

Comment: You are right, need use: my_item.current_cost.first, but with scope you can easily add more conditions